# absolute position in a React Native Modal is inconsistent on different devices

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React Native app. I have a button on the screen. When the user clicks the button, I make a little menu pop up adjacent to the button using a `Modal` component. The menu is positioned absolutely inside the Modal.

Issue: the y-position is inconsistent among devices. It's perfect on iPhone. On iPhone X it's about 20 pixels above where I want it. On Android it's about 4px above where I want it.

The button (which is also position:absolute) does not have this problem. It appears in the same location on every device.

Answer (score 2):

The x/y coordinate system in React-Native's `Modal` component has it's origin (0,0) at the top left of the status bar.

Other views have their (0,0) point at the top edge but **below** the status bar.

Therefore absolute y position within a Modal must be increased by the height of the status bar.

**However**, the status bar is different heights on different devices so you'll have to check it in your code. In fact, I think status bar height can change, for example when you have a call-in-progress bar at the top of the screen.

To get status bar height on Android is easy:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
statusBarHeight = StatusBar.currentHeight;
```

On IOS a bit tougher:

```
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';
NativeModules.StatusBarManager.getHeight(result => {
    statusBarHeight = result.height;
});
```

The IOS `getHeight()` takes a callback for its argument, so you will probably need to use a Promise.